# Openlayers JS issue

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, features

I am trying to combine two JS functions in a WMS; drawing features and getting/showing the coordinates of features, e.g. by clicking the drawn features afterwards.

I can manage to draw features by using this openlayers example; http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html

As I understand I should use the function 'drawend' to get coordinates of the drawn features?

How do I combine these two functions in the script? I am new to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this inside the function addInteraction

```
function addInteraction() {
  draw.on('drawend', function(e2) {
     var feature = e2.feature;
    var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

    var lon, lat;

    coords.forEach(function(latlon) {
    console.log(latlon)
    });

  });
}
```

now inside view you need to change the projection to 'EPSG:4326', so it will give you the lat and lon not coordinates

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4,
   projection: 'EPSG:4326',

  })
});
```

heres a working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZggEg?&editors=1010

Comment: Hi! Exacly where should I embed the code into the script? =)

Comment: I Just updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can´t see the coordinates anywhere in the working example? How do I see them? =)

Comment: I have updated the codepen, it will now display lon and lat on the html

Comment: This helped me a lot. It Works perfect! Thanks a lot for your help!